# XGBRegressor high train and test score but predicts is bad

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, xgboost

I am new in Data Science and have a problem.
This is my train and test score

```
Train Score : 99.99319245627736
Test Score  : 94.20448487131814
```

and this is my actual price and predict

```
            Actual_price  predict_price  Error
4928          162000         165994  -3994.343750
11272         31000          50525   -19525.128906
7894          110000         117209  -7209.609375
4382          59500          75478   -15978.164062
345           500000         482369   17630.968750
...             ...            ...           ...
3348          42750          38110    4639.328125
8993          74000          96511   -22511.226562
8270          83750          74911    8838.210938
2757          77500          89780   -12280.585938
6538          95000          92607    2392.765625
```

i have high scores but predicts is bad, where i am doing wrong. This is my code

```py
data_train, data_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.3,random_state=782)
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,max_depth=14)
model.fit(data_train, label_train)
print(model)
print("Train Score:"+str(model.score(data_train, label_train) * 100))
print("Test Score:"+str(model.score(data_test, label_test) * 100))
pre = model.predict(data_test)
out = pd.DataFrame({'Actual_price': label_test, 'predict_price': pre.astype(int), 'Error': (label_test - pre)})
print(out)
```

Comment: Why are you surprised? Train performance will generally always be better than test performane.

Comment: I'm not surprised i know that the training score should be higher than the test score. My problem is the big difference between the true price and the predicted price. 
I should get smaller error value with these scores. Am i wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without the actual dataset.

Comment: The errors are mostly an order of magnitude less than the values.  If you want to focus on some measure other than the default `score` (R-squared), then report those scores, and consider hyperparameter tuning for that score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, training accuracy is bigger than test, that's completely reasonable (as you already said).

Secondly, let's check the relative error(Error/Actual) you are making when predicting:

```
            Actual_price  predict_price  Error          Relative Error
4928          162000         165994  -3994.343750         2.5%
11272         31000          50525   -19525.128906        62,9%
7894          110000         117209  -7209.609375         6,5%
4382          59500          75478   -15978.164062        26,5%
345           500000         482369   17630.968750        3,5%
...             ...            ...           ...
3348          42750          38110    4639.328125         10,8%
8993          74000          96511   -22511.226562        30%
8270          83750          74911    8838.210938         10%
2757          77500          89780   -12280.585938        15%
6538          95000          92607    2392.765625         2,5%
```

With this calculated measure, we can say that the 94% accuracy you obtained is reasonable (except the sample 11272).
Obviously, this relative error is not the same as R square, but it's indicative. (To calculate de R square, all the dataset is needed)

As a conclusion, the R square that you obtained seems to be true. And take in consideration de **relativity**, for example, an error of 1,000 when your real value is 1,000,000 is good enough, but if your real value is 2,000 this is a huge error.